# initialise instances inside a class php

Tags: php

How do I initialize objects inside a function within a class? so I can call each object like `page[0]->getTitle();` or `page[1]->getDescription();`

The error now says :
 **Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\class.page.php on line 92**

index.php

```
Page::createObjects();
```

and my page.class.php

```
private title;
private description;
private page;

public function __construct($title="", $description=""){
  $this->title = $title;
  $this->description = $description;
}

public static function createObjects(){
  $database = new database();
  $database->query('SELECT * FROM pages');
  for($i=0;$i<$totalRows;$i++){
    //line 92 here
    $this->page[$i] = new self("Title", "Description");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't access `$this` from a **static** function.  How would it know which instance to modify?  Why is `$page` part of the class?  Why not have `createObjects()` *return* an array?

Comment: Just because you have called the file blah.class.php doesn't make it a class.  Where is the "class page { ..." part of your class...?

Comment: Do you *really* create a new database object every time you runs a query? Yikes.

Comment: I have thought about this. But I can't figure another way of doing it instead of putting it in index.php

Comment: No, I don't create new database object every time, I pass it as an argument into the function. This is just an example

Comment: `$this->page[$i]` cannot be used in a `"public static function"` you would need to use `self::page[$i]`

Comment: @JustinE I've tried this, it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in line 92

Comment: Try `self::$page[$i]` because the fact still remains that you are indeed `using $this when not in object context`...

Comment: And, why do you have a constructor in a class that contains static methods? When calling a function statically, it does not load the constructor.

Comment: @JustinE now it says Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Post::$post in line 92

Comment: Does it mean new self("Title", "Description") would not load its constructor?

Comment: So that's easy, the property $post does not exist in your Post class. If it does, it is not defined as a static property...i.e. `static $post;` you should probably consider putting more of your code on here if you want a solution. I won't code your project for you, but I don't mind helping you get to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider having two different classes here, `Page` (page.class.php) and `Pages` (pages.class.php).  Your `Page` class will represent an individual page record from your database, and your `Pages` class will contain methods that work on a set of records.

page.class.php

```
<?php
class Page

    private title;
    private description;

    public function __construct($title="", $description=""){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description();
    }
}
?>
```

pages.class.php

```
<?php
class Pages

    public static function createObjects(){
        $pages = array();
        $database = new database();
        $database->query('SELECT * FROM pages');
        for($i=0;$i<$totalRows;$i++){
            //line 92 here
            $pages[] = new Page("Title", "Description");
        }

        return $pages;
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your index.php, you get your `Page` objects from `Pages`

index.php

```
<?php

$pages = Pages::createObjects();

// to get the title of the first object
echo $pages[0]->getTitle();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now! But would you say it's a bad code or good code? Shall I avoid using them?

Comment: It's neither inherently good nor bad. It all comes down to how you use it. I would question your desire to create objects for _all_ rows from your table. That seems excessive and potentially problematic.

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering what if I have 1000+ pages, what would happen? Would it be very slow? Or is it down to how fast the server is? And what method should I use instead if not creating objects for each page

Comment: Umm, you would have over 1000 objects of the same type in your script. Your memory usage would skyrocket, and your site would be incredibly slow.

Comment: I would be less concerned about speed of returning the data and more concerned about potentially hitting your application's memory limit. The best solution is going to be dependent upon your particular use-case. It sounds like you could probably benefit from some general program design/architecture education/consultation that goes beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Like others commented, you can't access `$this` from a static function

a static field/variable/property/method belong to the class, not to a specific instance

```
<?php

class VIP
{
    private $name, $surname;
    private static $vips = array();

    function __construct($name, $surname){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
        self::$vips[] = $this;
    }

    function getCredentials(){
        return $this->name . ", " . $this->surname;
    }

    static function getAll(){
        return self::$vips;
    }
}

$a = new VIP("George", "Clooney");
$b = new VIP("Scarlet", "Johansson");
$c = new VIP("Brad", "Pitt");
$d = new VIP("Emma", "Stone");

echo $a->getCredentials() . "\n";

foreach(VIP::getAll() as $vip)
    echo $vip->getCredentials() . "\n";

?>
```

demo: https://eval.in/161874

however, this is more than likely bad code, since you are a beginner you should forget of static fields and methods and just use regular ones

---

better code:

```
<?php

class VIP
{
    private $name, $surname;

    function __construct($name, $surname){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    function getCredentials(){
        return $this->name . ", " . $this->surname;
    }
}

class VIPsList
{
    private $storage = [];

    function add(VIP $vip){
        $this->storage[] = $vip;
    }

    function getAll(){
        return $this->storage;
    }
}

$a = new VIP("George", "Clooney");
$b = new VIP("Scarlet", "Johansson");
$c = new VIP("Brad", "Pitt");
$d = new VIP("Emma", "Stone");

$collection = new VIPsList();
$collection->add($a);
$collection->add($b);
$collection->add($c);
$collection->add($d);

echo $a->getCredentials() . "\n";

foreach($collection->getAll() as $vip)
    echo $vip->getCredentials() . "\n";

?>
```

https://eval.in/161898

Comment: Static methods are not OOP. It is never a good idea to mix OOP with Static method calls.

Comment: @JustinE Thanks! Now I understand why I don't see static methods in Java

Comment: because it is not object oriented! because you might need to have two or more collections of VIPs instead of just a global one, you can't use polymorphism with static and the list goes on and on... eventually you will understand by yourself why they are bad, for now just try to not use them! as i said you can achieve the same result using a second class called VIPsList that collects VIPs instances

Comment: Now @MacroR88, there are times where it is good to use Static Methods, I.e. if you have a group of functions that you just want to keep together for use in your application, like in a database class (bad example) or a configuration class (good example)

Comment: @JustinE imho, no! you should use static only when a "type" or "a set of functions" is stateless, such as the java/javascript Math class, which just groups together functions and constants. another fine case might be multiple constructors (overloading)

Comment: Granted, but what I am saying is at his level, he could be using a set of constants in a class that he is using for his application's configuration. These settings are stateless. My scenario is viable for someone who is just starting out in PHP. Whereas, overloading may not be something a beginner would know much about.

Comment: And furthermore, a database class could in theory be stateless.

DB::init($connection_array);
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM table");